# Dividing a string into groups of four

Tags: java, algorithm, substring

Input is;

```
"AbrAcadAbRa"
```

Output should be;

```
["AbrA", "brAc", "rAca", "Acad", "cadA", "adAb", "dAbR", "AbRa]
```

This is what I've tried so far, without success;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = "AbrAcadAbRa";
    int length = 4;
    String subString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        subString = str.substring(i, length);
        System.out.println(subString);
        str = str.substring(i);
    }
}
```

It is giving the wrong output;

```
["AbrA", "brA", "Ac", "d"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your logic for iterating over the string is incorrect, hence your current results.  The logic I used below is to iterate over the entire length of the *input string*, minus however much space is needed to ensure that the appropriate length substring can be taken.  Then, in each iteration, print out a `length` substring.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "AbrAcadAbRa";
    int length = 4;
    String subString = "";
    // iterate over the length of the input, offset by the substring length
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-length+1; i++) {
        subString = str.substring(i, i+length);
        System.out.println(subString);
        // this is wrong; don't modify the original string
        //str = str.substring(i);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
AbrA
brAc
rAca
Acad
cadA
adAb
dAbR
AbRa
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code. You have to compute length of your string.

int len = str.length();

And start a loop from `0` to `len-3` because you want 4 digit per string. So yo cannot go after last letter.
I put the sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = "AbrAcadAbRa";
    int len = str.length();
    int length = 4;
    String subString = "";
    for(int j = 0;j<len-3;j++){
        subString = str.substring(j, j+4);
        System.out.println(subString);
       }
    }
```

output

```
AbrA
brAc
rAca
Acad
cadA
adAb
dAbR
AbRa
```

Comment: The bounds of your `for` loop aren't very desirable, because they have hard-coded the desired substring length of 4.

Answer (score 0):

With streams you can do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "AbrAcadAbRa";
    int length = 4;
    IntStream.range(0, s.length() - length + 1)
             .forEach(i -> System.out.println(s.substring(i, i + length)));
}
```

It creates a stream of integers up to the last `length` characters and then prints the substring starting from each one to `length`.

Output:

> AbrA
>   brAc
>   rAca
>   Acad
>   cadA
>   adAb
>   dAbR
>   AbRa

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "AbrAcadAbRa";

        String newstr = str;
        String sub;
        int length = 4;

        for (int i=0 ; i<str.length()-3 ; i++){
            sub = newstr.substring(0, length);
            newstr = newstr.substring(1, newstr.length());
            System.out.println(sub);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Dumping code without explanation is bad. Also, the OP gave you a `length` parameter, use that.